# "IS NOT NULL" conditions for associations in Thinking Sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

How do you add an "IS NOT NULL" condition for associations in Thinking Sphinx search? For example if we have an article model which has the following index..

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :article, :with => :active_record do
  indexes subject, :sortable => true
  indexes content
  has pictures(:id), as: :picture_ids
end
```

..and we want to search for all articles which contain a certain keyword and have a picture. Articles and pictures are related by a simple `has_many`  relationship

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, -> { where 'pictures.type' => 'ArticlePicture' }
```

The following line used to work, as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258378/how-do-i-add-the-condition-is-not-null-to-a-thinking-sphinx-search), but it no longer seems to work :-(

```
Article.search(keyword, without: {picture_ids: 0})
```

What is the correct way to do it? I am using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) `2.2.10` and [thinking-sphinx](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/) `3.2.0`

Comment: Not a TS expert, but does "has pictures(:id), " imply a relation? Ie the picture ids are loaded from a separate database table. If so possibly two problems, A) ends up running a 'INNER JOIN' rather than 'LEFT JOIN' on the tables, so records without any pictures are simply missing. But also B) if ends up being a Sphinx MVA, then when no pics, is an empty list rather than a list with single 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional attribute with a SQL snippet:

```
has "COUNT(DISTINCT pictures.id)", :as => :picture_count, :type => :integer
```

And then - once you've run `rake ts:rebuild` - I'd expect the following to work:

```
Article.search(keyword, :without => {:picture_count => 0})
```

It's important to note that you'll still need a reference to the `pictures` association in your index definition to ensure there's a SQL join. This is done by your existing attribute (`picture_ids`), or otherwise you can force the join using the following line within the index definition:

```
join pictures
```